# How do I properly set text onto a dynamically loaded image?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a custom array adapter where each item consists of two textviews over an imageview(SmartImageView is a third party imageview that renders remote images from a url):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Data Model Title"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Data Model Details"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I see the image with a top and bottom margin and no text:

1) the RelativeLayout with the text should go over the image since it is the 2nd child of FrameLayout

2) why is there a margin above and below my image?  I said my imageview's dimensions were match parent, and didnt specify any top or bottom margins for it

Answer (score 0):

1. It should and it actually does.  The text didn't show up for a different reason.
2. I added android:scaleType="centerCrop" which filled the row completely.